# iOS 11.3 update, text color is dimmed

Tags: ios, objective-c, textcolor

Does anyone having issue changing text colour as initially my app was working fine with bright white colour as a text label colour but when i installed the latest iOS update, i am having issue while changing the colour as those does look dimmed as initially those were bright and was readable.

Also all the pods which i am using for alert-controller has the same dimmed title along with button label text colour.

Any idea how to fix it as i am unable to find any help regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C,

```
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Dont care what goes here, since we're about to change below" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
alertVC.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // your custom color
NSMutableAttributedString *hogan = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Presenting the great... Hulk Hogan!"];
[hogan addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50.0]
              range:NSMakeRange(24, 11)];
[alertVC setValue:hogan forKey:@"attributedTitle"];



UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Label text" 
                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                                    //add code to make something happen once tapped
}];
```